# Error in Adding libwebrtc.aar library

Tags: android

When i am trying to add the webRTC aar library file to my project its throwing below exception.I am adding library from project structure.Can someone help me ?.

E:/libwebrtc.aar
com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileTooBigException: E:/libwebrtc.aar
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualFileImpl.checkNotTooLarge(VirtualFileImpl.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualFileImpl.contentsToByteArray(VirtualFileImpl.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualFileImpl.contentsToByteArray(VirtualFileImpl.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VfsUtilCore.copyFile(VfsUtilCore.java:225)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VfsUtilCore.copyFile(VfsUtilCore.java:207)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VfsUtil.copy(VfsUtil.java:107)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.importing.CreateModuleFromArchiveAction.run(CreateModuleFromArchiveAction.java:141)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$null$1(WriteCommandAction.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1023)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$performWriteCommandAction$2(WriteCommandAction.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.lambda$doExecuteCommand$4(WriteCommandAction.java:210)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.doExecuteCommand(WriteCommandAction.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:151)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.importing.ArchiveToGradleModuleModel.handleFinished(ArchiveToGradleModuleModel.java:93)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:390)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:324)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:305)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1838)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1696)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1645)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewModuleAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewModuleAction.java:67)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:190)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:327)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:736)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1696)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1645)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.lambda$show$0(SettingsDialog.java:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.show(SettingsDialog.java:77)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGet(DialogWrapper.java:1660)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:238)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:204)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.doShowDialog(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.showDialogAndSelect(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:134)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.editors.AndroidProjectSettingsService.openModuleSettings(AndroidProjectSettingsService.java:91)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.PsiDirectoryNode.navigate(PsiDirectoryNode.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigate(OpenSourceUtil.java:53)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.BaseNavigateToSourceAction.actionPerformed(BaseNavigateToSourceAction.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:929)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Please add some relevant code

Comment: have you solved this?

Answer (score 6):

I too faced an similar issue when importing xwalk_core_library.aar in Android Studio 3.0

To solve this issue, add the following property in "idea.properties" file

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=102400
```

The above value will be taken as KB by Android Studio.
The idea.properties file could be opened within Android Studio through "Help -> Find Action -> Edit Custom Properties"

Comment: You need to restart Android Studio for this to take effect.