# Cannot import AAR

Tags: android-studio, aar

I want to import an aar library in Android Studio 3.0.1.

I try it via `File/New Module/Import .JAR/.AAR package` as well as from `File/Project Structure/+ (New Module)`.

In both cases the AAR module fails to show up in `Project Structure/Modules` and consequently I cannot add a module dependency (`Choose module` window has "Nothing to show").

It should work like described in, e.g., http://docs.onemobilesdk.aol.com/android-ad-sdk/adding-aar-files.html - but it doesn't.

So what have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be related to this question: [Error in Adding libwebrtc.aar library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229411/error-in-adding-libwebrtc-aar-library) - I'd overseen the detailed exception of the "Android support" plugin.

After changing this

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=102400
```

in file `idea.properties` (located in Android Studio's `bin` subfolder of installation directory), the AAR could be added successfully.